# Pod rollout is only successful after cordon

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I've got some pods whose rollout is only successful after a cordon.

The `kubectl rollout status` fails within our pipeline.

We'll cordon the node that the app was initially deployed to.

After getting a new node the pods rollout just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the state of the pod before cordoning the node? What is the result of `kubectl describe pod` when the pod is not scheduled?

Comment: What is the state of the pod before cordoning the node  is `CrashLoopBackOff`. What is the result of kubectl describe pod when the pod is not scheduled is `Environment timeout`

Comment: I've never heard of `Environment timeout`, can you please add a screenshot to the question?